# Ошибка Run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'nazvtov'

Tags: c, структуры, динамические-массивы, runtime, переполнение

В общем, вроде все делал нормально, но в конце, при выдаче ответа, вылетает ошибка run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable 'nazvtov' was corrupted
Когда я успеваю выйти за пределы строки и как это исправить?..

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define limtov 1 // ограничиваю количество товаров
#define limst 1 // ограничиваю количество стран, импортирующих товар
struct svedeniya {
 char nazv;
 char exportstr;
 int volume;
 char *import;
};

void vvod(svedeniya *tovar) {
 int i = 0; 
 int j = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < limtov; i++){
  tovar[i].import = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
  printf("\nВведите название товара №%d: ", i);
   scanf("%s", &tovar[i].nazv); 
  printf("\nВведите страну, экспортирующую товар№%d: ", i);
   scanf("%s", &tovar[i].exportstr);
  printf("\nВведите общий объем товара в штуках№%d: ", i);
   scanf("%d", &tovar[i].volume);
  for (j = 0; j < limst; j++) {
   printf("\nВведите страну №%d, в которые импортируется товар№%d: ", j, i);
   scanf("%s", &tovar[i].import[j]);
  }
 }
}

void poisk(svedeniya *tovar) {
 char nazvtov;
 int i = 0;
 printf("Введите товар для поиска: ");
 scanf("%s", &nazvtov);
 for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  if (strcmp(&nazvtov, &tovar[i].nazv) == 0){
   printf("%s ", &tovar[i].nazv);
   printf("%s ", &tovar[i].exportstr);
   for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    printf("%s ", &tovar[i].import[j]);
   }
  }
 }
}

int main() {
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
 svedeniya *tovar;
 tovar = (svedeniya*)malloc(sizeof(svedeniya));
 vvod(tovar);
 poisk(tovar);



}
```

Comment: В общем, выделил память под каждую строку и теперь у меня ошибка "Нарушение доступа при чтении"

Answer (score 1):

У вас `nazvtov` - это один-единственный символ. В один символ можно запихнуть только пустую строку. Вы же, очевидно, пытаетесь пихать в него непустую строку. Разумеется получается выход за пределы.

У вас во всем коде для хранения строк почему-то объявлен поля типа `char`. За исключением какого-то странного поля `import`, которое внезапно имеет тип `char *`, но под которое все равно выделяется один-единственный `char`. Каким это образом вы собрались хранить строки в таких полях размером в один символ???

Comment: Большое спасибо. Понял, в каком направлении двигаться. Попробовал сделать каждую строку динамическим массивом, не получается решить проблему